# Dial phone number with TEL protocol

Tags: acumatica

I am very new to Acumatica development, but as a basic start, we would like to be able to add a button after phone number textboxes to enable dialing from Skype for Business with the TEL protocol `TEL: +1-###-###-####`.  I have the button inserted correctly, and am overriding the *NavigateURL*, and it works perfectly if I put a phone number directly in the url.  However, I'm looking for a way to place-hold the actual phone number value instead.. Something like `TEL: [Contact.Phone1]`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think NavigateURL is meant to be use like a template engine with variables. What I would do is format the URL in the Action event handler and use PXRedirectToUrlException to open the link.

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Skype")]
[PXButton]
public virtual IEnumerable SkypeButton(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    Contact contact = base.Caches[typeof(Contact)].Current as Contact;

    if (contact != null)
    {
        throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(string.Format("tel:{0}", contact.Phone1.Trim()),
                                           PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow,
                                           string.Empty);
    }

    return adapter.Get();
}
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble with this.  I have it working, but I have a problem. Clicking the 'Call' button on a record opened from a generic inquiry screen results in an error.  I traced the logs, and it's passing in `tel:+17173978880?PopupPanel=Inline` and `tel:+17173624476?7678772635=465463`  If I refresh the page of the current record, then it works correctly.  Do you know why it is adding in the extras?

Comment: The first one might be related to PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode, the second one I have no clue where it's coming from. Inquiry screens are pretty limited in what they can do, I'm unsure if your error can be fixed.

Comment: I tried your redirect method.  I also tried `throw new Exception("Redirect0: tel:{0} .....)  Same thing.

Comment: I meant changing WindowMode, perhaps if you redirect it to the same window it won't try to append the PopupPanel parameters.

Comment: I'm struggling to find any documentation on this.  Could you so kindly give me the alternate WindowMode code?

Comment: Just try other WindowMode for redirect like WindowMode.Same. here are the enums public enum WindowMode
{
 Same = 0,
 New = 1,
 Popup = 2,
 NewWindow = 3,
 InlineWindow = 4
}

Comment: I apologize to bring this up again, but the latest update to Acumatica broke what we had somewhat working with `throw new Exception(string.Format("Redirect0: tel:+1{0}", contact.Phone1.Trim()));`  Disregarding best practice and whatever other drawbacks there are to using this type of approach, is there any way, (by JS or any other means) that we could get this to work?  I've researched it again, but the context for most answers is different than Acumatica's, and I'm losing ground.  I would appreciate any help, however unconventional it may be.

Comment: What evidence you have that this feature broke? In the code example I provided notice I throw a PXRedirectToUrlException. In your comment you are using PXException.

Comment: It never worked with PXRedirectToUrlException.  The only way I could get it to pass without the extra parameters was to use PXException with 'Redirect0'.  But this also now passes parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by it never worked? Redirect0 is not officially supported, this is a hack that relied on undocumented behavior. If you want to redirect the API is PXRedirectToUrlException not PXException and it does require 3 parameters as per my example.

Comment: The only way I can see PXRedirectToUrlException failing is when used on page load, ex constructor. It has to be used in an event handler from the web page, like an Action button.

Comment: I am aware.  I tried this originally, and it does what it is designed to do.  It requires parameters, which in turn pass their parameters into the URL.  This causes Skype to choke, because it is expecting a TEL formatted phone number, and instead gets something like `tel:+17173978880?PopupPanel=Inline`.  `Redirect0` was a hack that allowed it to redirect without passing the 'inline' parameter in the URL, therefore allowing it to function as a TEL call. But this now also passes the same parameters.  I'm asking if there is any way to pass a URL containing no 'window mode' parameters. Hack or no.

Comment: Yes, you can pick any of the public constructor from RedirectToUrl exception, some don't have a newWindow parameter:
public PXRedirectToUrlException(string url, string message);
public PXRedirectToUrlException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context);
public PXRedirectToUrlException(string url, string format, params object[] args);

Comment: I don't really understand the root issue here though. With Microsoft Edge browser if I put exactly "tel:+17173978880?PopupPanel=Inline" in the URL bar it does open with Skype.

Comment: It does open with Skype, but does it open the call?  It always gives an error for us about the formatting being wrong.  I will try a different constructor.

Comment: It seems the Tel URI RFC doesn't define a end delimiter but you can try putting a semi-colon as a end delimiter of the TEL URI "tel:+17173978880;?PopupPanel=Inline". TEL URI reference https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3966

Comment: For Skype new UWC app, it seems that's not necessary and your TEL URI  format seems fine to me: http://i64.tinypic.com/21bstnr.png

Comment: Slight difference, but this is Skype for Business.